# How to concatenate in PHP?

Tags: php, web, concatenation

Create a variable called fullName and assign it a value equal to the concatenation of the firstName variable, a space, the middleName variable, a space, and the lastName variable.

I have :

```
$firstName = "Tony";
$middleName = "Muscles";
$lastName = "Montana";
```

Why doesn't the following work?

```
$fullName = $firstName." ".$middleName." ".$lastName
```

Comment: cause you forgot the semi-colon at the end of the line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing the semicolon:

```
$fullName = $firstName.' '.$middleName.' '.$lastName;
```